# Basic Http server PUT request in java

Tags: java, http, server, request, put

I'm currently learning on how to use HTTP request with java I've done a GET request that works properly :

```
static class ThermostatHandler implements HttpHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
        String requestMethod = he.getRequestMethod();
        if (requestMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {
            String response = Smart.thermostatsGlobal;
            addResponseHeader(he);
            he.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            try (OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody()) {
                os.write(response.getBytes());
            } 
        }             
    }
}
```

Now im trying to do a PUT request but can't find any help using these imports :

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
```

I cannot use different imports I can add some tho using the *.httpserver.*

Any help on how to send data lets say to Smart.thermostatsGlobal but with a PUT it could be any type of data but I would prefer a string

the route is localhost:8000/thermostats

Thank you

EDIT:

Its for learning purposes I need to use those sun packages sadly and im on java 8

Comment: Which Java version are you on? You are not supposed to use `com.sun` or `sun` packages, they are JVM internal.

Comment: If you are using Java 11, then use the [Java 11 HTTP client](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html) in the package `java.net.http` instead of internal `com.sun` classes.

Comment: I edited I need to use JAVA 8 and for learning purposes I need to use those packages if not what would you recommend ?!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? Do you want to *receive* and*handle* a PUT request as you're doing with a GET request in the posted code? Or do you want to *send* a PUT request? If you want to send a PUT request, without any additional dependency, use HttpUrlConnection. If you want to receive one, then use the same as the one you posted, and test if the request method is PUT instead of testing if it's GET.

Comment: I want to handle a put request sent from postman that will change the smart thermostat temperature

Comment: So add an `else if (requestMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("PUT")) { // do what you want here }`.

Comment: I get that i just dont know how to parse the bye/data that comes from a put request :S thats my question in the end : how to handle the data from the put

Comment: It's impossible to tell you how to parse a request body if you don't say what the request body contains.

Comment: The request body will contains a string. Thank you for your time

Comment: So, your question is actually: how do I read characters from an InputStream? Use an InputStreamReader. Check out its javadoc. Google for Java IO tutorial.

Comment: Thank you ! Talking helps me a lot in the way i will approach this it made me realise it wasnt that easy im just stressed